# Convert ros markers into pcl or mesh

Tags: ros, pcl, markers, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am a newbie in ROS. Recently, I start working on the SLAM method(developed by someone else ). I have a node which publishes to the topic /Map. The messages are of type: visualization_msgs/Marker. Example:

 x: 0.0703901350498
y: 0.258601367474
z: 0.103628642857
However, the output I wanted is something like point cloud or mesh so that I can import them into simulators like Gazebo. I tried some research online but none of the results answer my question. I wonder if it is possible to convert those Markers into pointcloud or mesh?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229829/convert-ros-markers-into-pcl-or-mesh/) by [rosGSCOP](https://answers.ros.org/users/26364/rosgscop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2016-03-22**:
Can you let us know which type of marker message you are receiving? There are quite a lot of types. If the marker message is points or triangles, then you could make your own node to convert these into point clouds using PCL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check the [`sensor_msgs/PointCloud`](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) type you can see that it contains an array of points of type [`geometry_msgs/Point32`](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Point32.html) that have member variables x, y and z. So you can write a node that listens to your markers topic, extract the points coordinates, puts them into the PointCloud message and republish that message.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0